# how can I do database operations between associated tables in a clean way?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I never really designed a database myself, I only worked with existing ones, so right now I have a little difficulty designing one from scratch for my exam.
**I'll use mssql with entity framework**, I already have some associations, currently my database design looks something like this:

[image: here is my database design]

Basically I want to substract from the 'inStorageAmount' field in the ingredients table after every order, based on number of items ordered.

it would go something like this:

```
for all ordered_product do =>
    select coffee from products table where ordered_product.coffee_id equals products.coffeId
     select from productIngredients where products.coffeeId equals productIngredients.coffee_id
          where selected productIngredients.ingredient_id equals ingredients.ingredientId 
            update => ingredients.inStorageAmount equals ingredients.inStorageAmount - productIngredients.amount * ordered_product.quantity
```

It's similar story for updating an order's TotalPrice when adding/removing products.

```
product added => look at products => based on quantity and price => update orders.TotalPrice
```

I feel like it's not the best solution for a "serious" application, what are some cleaner ways of doing it?

Comment: I think your customers are going to be P.O.'d if you change the price on them after the order has been placed...

Comment: I think that maybe what you are asking is "how do I update my data store in a transaction". That allows you to commit a set of operations all at once, or roll them back on failure.

Comment: I don't really change the price on a placed order. My orders count as placed after they are completed.  My order flow will go like this: customer puts something in the cart => new order will be created along the ordered_product, order's TotalPrice gets updated based on ordered_product. At this point, the order is only in draft status, products can be added and deleted from it. Once the customer pays it will go into "completed" status (placed), and you can't modify it anymore.